# Prove/Disprove $f(z)=0$ if and only if $z=0$ for a power series $f$ about the centre $0$ having radius of convergence $2$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Q. Let $f(z)$ be a power-series (with complex coefficients) centred at $0 \in \mathbb{C}$ and with a radius of convergence $2$ . Suppose that $f(0)=0$. Choose the correct statement(s) from below:

(A) $f^{-1}(0)=\{0\}$

(B) If $f$ is a non-constant function on $\{z \in \Bbb C~:~|z|<2\}$, then $f^{-1}(0)=\{0\}$;

(C) If $f$ is a non-constant function, then for all $\zeta \in \Bbb C$ with sufficiently small $|\zeta|$, the equation $f(z)=\zeta$ has a solution;

(D) $\int_\gamma f^{(n)}(z) d z=0$ for every $n \geq 1$, where $\gamma$ is a unit circle centred at $0$ , oriented clockwise, and $f^{(n)}$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative of $f(z)$.

How can I confirm $f(z)=0$ if and only if $z=0$, in the geometric series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}z^n$, I got first option is true, but how to generalize. Option D says all the coefficients of the terms is zero, I feel it is impossible.

Comment: @eggnog How can B be true? Consider $f(z)=\frac{z(z-1)}{z-2}$ for a function with power series having exactly radius of convergence $=2$ an two roots in the corresponding disk

Comment: Oh you're right.   I also misread $D$.  @HagenvonEitzen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A and B: These are both *false*. We can use the same counterexample for both claims. Let $f(z) = \frac{z(z-1)}{z-2}$. Then $f(0) = f(1) = 0$. Also $f$ is holomorphic on the disc $|z| < 2$, but it has a pole at $z=2$, so the power series expansion around $z=0$ has radius of convergence = 2.

EDIT: A comment asked why it follows that the power series for $f$ around $z=0$ has RoC=2. It's because of the fact: "*The radius of convergence is always the distance from the center to the nearest non-removable singularity; if there are no singularities (i.e., if $f$ is an entire function), then the radius of convergence is infinite.*" The proof is included in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions).

C: This is *true*. It's the [Open Mapping Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)). $f$ is holomorphic on a neighborhood of $z=0$, so the range of $f$ is an open set containing $0$ and therefore the range of $f$ includes all points that are sufficiently close to $0$.

D: This is *true*. It's [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem). We know $f$ is holomorphic on $|z|<2$, so $f^{(n)}$ is also defined and holomorphic on that disc, so this is exactly the situation covered by that theorem.

Comment: How can we see $f(z)=0$ as a power series about origin with a radius of convergence $2$.

Comment: @Riaz I edited the answer to add a link to the proof of this theorem.

Comment: The radius of convergence of $\sum 0 z^n$ is $\infty$ and not $2$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yep, you got me. Edited to just use the same example for A and B. Kinda weird that the problem statement talks about whether the function is constant, if we need the radius of convergence to be exactly 2.

Comment: @DavidClyde I think you have taken a point $\zeta$ sufficiently close to $0$ means $\zeta$ has to come inside any neighborhood of $0$, right? If it were, $\zeta$ has to be zero due to the metric nature of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @Riaz I guess you're talking about C, right? $f$ is a holomorphic function defined on the open domain $|z|<2$, so the Open Mapping Theorem says that the image of $f$ must be an open set too. We know the image of $f$ contains 0 because $f(0) = 0$, so the image of $f$ must contain some open disc around 0 too, say $|z|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: @DavidClyde what is the necessity for $\zeta$ to come inside the image neighborhood?

Comment: @DavidClyde I have a vague idea about 'sufficiently close to', can you clarify me? thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's the careful official definition: If we say $f(z) = \zeta$ has a solution for all $\zeta \in \mathbb{C}$ with sufficiently small $|\zeta|$, that means we can choose some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that if $|\zeta| < \varepsilon$ then $f(z) = \zeta$ has a solution.

Here's a more intuitive way to think about it: If some statement is true for all $\zeta \in \mathbb{C}$ with sufficiently small $|\zeta|$, that means there's a tiny open disc around $0$ where the statement always holds if $\zeta$ is in that disc.

Comment: note that the open ball $B\big(0, r\big)$ where $r$ is the radius of convergence an of analytic function at zero, is a subset of its domain.  If we define $f:D\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ with $D$ being the open 2-disc, then we can have situations where $f$ is a constant function with a radius of convergence of $2$.  Further not all texts require 'a radius of convergence' to be maximal-- e.g. Beardon explicitly does not.   This helps explain why (b) and (c) in the OP explicitly exclude constant $f$ .